# Forge 3-Legged Oauth - How to use different redirect url's in my application

Tags: autodesk-forge

Can somebody tell how the redirect_url works in combination with wildcards? In the help the info below is given:

*3-Legged Token
Generate an Authentication URL
To ask for permissions from a user to retrieve an access token, you redirect the user to a consent page. Replace your-client-id, your-client-secret, and your-redirect-url with your app's client ID, client secret, and redirect URL, and run the code to create a consent page URL. Note that the redirect URL must match the pattern of the callback URL field of the app’s registration in the My Apps section. The pattern may include wildcards after the hostname, allowing different redirect URL values to be specified in different parts of your app.*

I am particularly interested in: 'allowing different redirect URL values to be specified in different parts of your app'. Can somebody please provide a kind of step by step guide? Should be callback url in the registered app contain a wildcard?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Specifically for the case mentioned:

"The pattern may include wildcards after the hostname, allowing different redirect URL values to be specified in different parts of your app."

Let's use the [View BIM 360 & Fusion models](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels) sample.

In this sample, we have `http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth` as value for the *FORGE_CALLBACK_URL* environment variable.

As this value must match your Forge App CallBack URL (details [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/basics/)), you can have two approaches:

1 - Define them both the same way, as `http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth`. This way your authorization code will always be redirected to this URI.

2 - Define your Forge App CallBack URL using a wildcard, as `http://localhost:3000/*`. This way your authorization code can be redirected to other URIs like `http://localhost:3000/anyother`, for instance. The URI will be defined by `redirect_uri` from [GET authorize](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/authorize-GET/#query-string-parameters).

Comment: FYI - Our platform now accepts multiple callbacks